# Replace/update object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Struggling to replace/update object in array of objects. I have an array:

```
myArray = [
  {id: 0, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction()},
  {id: 1, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction()},
  {id: 2, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction()},
  {id: 3, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction()}
]
```

after using `.map` and executing the function I am getting an object for example as:

```
{id: 2, description: "some description", status: "newStatus", function: someFunction()},
```

The idea is after receiving an object with the same id as it is in an array that I update/replace the object from the array with the new one. If matters the id of the object in the array is same as the index of an array.

UPDATE:
`.map` function which I am using is:

```
    myArray.map(item =>
      item.function(x => {
        x
          ? setStatus({ ...item, status: 'newStatus' })
          : setStatus({ ...item, status: 'newStatus2' });
      })
    );
```

The function is a callback that using Math.random and returning the result which should be a new status. Result of the callback in this case can be `newStatus` or `newStatus2`. Function in each object starts to run on button click in the UI.

Comment: Please show us the code that uses `map` and calls the function, otherwise we can't help you fix it.

Comment: Added the update in description passing `map` function

Comment: What is `setStatus`? What do the `.function`s in your objects do, why do they take a callback, what do they pass for `x`? What are you doing with the return value of  the `.map()` call?

Comment: I believe something is wrong with your `.map` function, if you want to update the original array you can use forEach easily it `array.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)` , the second argument for the callback is an index in foreach loop so you can update the index of array you want to update. Also, if you want to create a new updated array you can use `.map` correctly `array.map(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)` as it will return a new array.

Answer (score 0):

The `myArray` contains objects with `function: someFunction()`, therefore, the value will be the **result** of the function, not the function itself.

So when you're trying to call the function, you should just handle the value.

```js
let myArray = [{ id: 0, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction() }, { id: 1, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction() }, { id: 2, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction() }, { id: 3, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction() } ];

myArray.map(item => {
   item.status = 'newStatus' + item.function;
});
console.log(myArray);

function someFunction() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}
```

---

Or, the other way around, if we remove the `()` from the `myArray.function`, we can call the function inside our `map()`:

```js
let myArray = [{ id: 0, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction }, { id: 1, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction }, { id: 2, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction }, { id: 3, description: "some description", status: "initial status", function: someFunction } ];

myArray.map(item => {
   item.status = 'newStatus' + item.function();
});
console.log(myArray);

function someFunction() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}
```